# java.lang.ClassCastException: StandaloneInMemProcessEngineConfiguration cannot be cast to org.activiti.spring.SpringProcessEngineConfiguration

Tags: java, activiti

I am using org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.StandaloneInMemProcessEngineConfiguration to instantiate processEngineConfiguration bean for unit testing purposes. But after upgrade to activiti 5.17.0 i got the ClassCastException.

Here is my activiti.cfg.xml

```
<bean name="processEngineConfiguration" class="org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.StandaloneInMemProcessEngineConfiguration" />
<bean id="processEngine" class="org.activiti.spring.ProcessEngineFactoryBean">
    <property name="processEngineConfiguration" ref="processEngineConfiguration" />
</bean>
```

Seems like in activiti-spring sources there used to be a condition

```
ProcessEngineFactoryBean.java
    if (processEngineConfiguration instanceof SpringProcessEngineConfiguration) { // remark: any config can be injected, so we cannot have SpringConfiguration as member
        SpringProcessEngineConfiguration engineConfiguration = (SpringProcessEngineConfiguration) processEngineConfiguration;
```

But now the configuration is always cast

```
SpringProcessEngineConfiguration engineConfiguration = (SpringProcessEngineConfiguration) processEngineConfiguration;
```

Is there a valid way to instantiate the in memory configuration?

Comment: Is that the entire and exact exception message???

Comment: #FIXED
https://github.com/Activiti/Activiti/pull/519